# How can one calculate the output voltage of the following circuit

Tags: voltage, voltage-divider

I have the following circuit. It has a hall sensor IC-MA3 which is connected to an op-amp. The signal has to be within 2.5V.

The outputs P[0:3] are sine and cosine signals with the middle being at 2.2V and 500mVpp.

As can be seen from the circuit, each of the output signals P[0:3] have a voltage divider circuit at the output. Is there anyway to calculate the output signals?

[image]

Edit:

I am uploading the circuit which i have tested and now works as i wanted.
The two images are of the respective hall sensor and also the opamp which i had not shared previously.[image]
[image].

The output of this circuit was to amplify and produce a signal from the hall sensor that would be in the limits of 2V to 2.7V(Not 2.5V as previously stated). These values are read from a dc motor to which this pcb is connected to.

Comment: What does "The signal has to be within 2.5V" mean? Do you want a signal with a range of 0V to 2.5V, or do you want a signal with a mid-point of 2.5V?

Comment: You write that this circuit is connected to an opamp, but I don't see any sign of that here. How is it connected to the opamp, and for what purpose? Should this opamp play any part in the answer you're expecting to your question?

Comment: @brhans, i realise the wording is not correct, and missing a lot of information. The signal should have a midpoint of 2.25V with 0.25V above and below, i.e., 2V to 2.5V.

Comment: i completed the circuit and was able to get it to run. I found out that a resistor value was wrong, also i had to rewire the connections to the opamp which is not shown here. The answer from @Simon Finch pointed me in the direction which opened my eyes to where i was making the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the nodes PSIN, NSIN etc. are not loaded in any way:

$$ V_{PSIN} = V_{P0} + (4.5V - V_{P0})\frac{3.6k\Omega}{3.6k\Omega + 2.4k\Omega} $$

$$ V_{NSIN} = V_{P1} + (4.5V - V_{P1})\frac{3.6k\Omega}{3.6k\Omega + 2.4k\Omega} $$

$$ V_{NCOS} = V_{P2} + (4.5V - V_{P2})\frac{3.6k\Omega}{3.6k\Omega + 2.4k\Omega} $$

$$ V_{PCOS} = V_{P3} + (4.5V - V_{P3})\frac{3.6k\Omega}{3.6k\Omega + 2.4k\Omega} $$

These simplify to:

$$ V_{PSIN} = 0.4V_{P0} + 2.7V $$

$$ V_{NSIN} = 0.4V_{P1} + 2.7V $$

$$ V_{NCOS} = 0.4V_{P2} + 2.7V $$

$$ V_{PCOS} = 0.4V_{P3} + 2.7V $$